# Why does the printer print an extra page containing "p://poppler.freedesktop.org"?

Tags: printing, pdf

I received an HP 255 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

When I print a PDF file on my Lexmark T640 it prints a extra page, on which the only text is:

> **p://poppler.freedesktop.org**

But for me it's a really big problem, because I print very much documents, and for any document I print, I print another blank page with "p://poppler.freedesktop.org".

How can I stop Ubuntu from printing this unnecessary extra page?

Answer (score 0):

[poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org) is a PDF rendering library. I've never encountered such problems while using PDF nor any docs when printing..

Anyhow, a quick search led me to something interesting which I think will help you to overcome your issue too.

**The default setting in Tools | Options | Writer | Print  is set to print an automatically inserted blank page.  All previous versions of Open Office (and Libre Office as far as I know) have NOT had this set as default, so I've never gone looking for it.**

**Source:** [extra page printing DOCX file in Writer](http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/4450)

**EDIT:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+bug/293832